# How to compile a simple multiboot2 bare-metal executable?

Tags: gcc, compilation, kernel, bootloader, grub

I want to start to write an os kernel, and then, i found a [document](http://nongnu.askapache.com/grub/phcoder/multiboot.pdf) introducing multboot2 spec.

There are three example code files, named `boot.S`, `kernel.c` and `multiboot2.h`, belonging to the `multiboot2` branch of `grub` project.

Firstly, i tried to compile and link the code with some option (using i686-elf-gcc) such as `-nostartfiles`, `-nodefaultlibs` and `-ffreestanding`, but qemu showed me the format was error.

And then i found a file named `Makefile.am`, and the compiler option in this file is `-fno-builtin -nostdinc -O -g -Wall`, and the linker option in this file is `-nostdlib -Wl,-N -Wl,-Ttext -Wl,80100000 -Wl,--build-id=none`.

So i built the kernel with options above, and qemu started to booting the kernel(`qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel`). But the kernel traped into infinite loop immediately.

So i cloned the branch of the project, and used gnulib to generate some files and started `make` but got some errors.

I don't show the error message here, because reading the document, i see what i need to do is just transforming `boot.S` to binary file and pasting it in the front of the compiled and non-linked kernel file(`kernel.o`), isn't it? How to complete it?

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial. Here's a how-to get a multiboot2 bare-metal executable set up using grub.

https://os.phil-opp.com/multiboot-kernel/

Try running the bare executable with `-kernel` and it will fail.

Try running the ISO containing grub and it will work.